# Multiple jCarousels with scroll buttons created by callback.

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I have a page where I'm trying to add several jCarousel elements.  One of these on its own works very nicely with the following code:

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {        
    jQuery('.next').bind('click', function() { carousel.next(); return false; });
    jQuery('.prev').bind('click', function() { carousel.prev(); return false; });
        };

// Load carousel...
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".featuredItems").jcarousel({
    scroll: 4,
    visible: 4,
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
    buttonNextHTML: null,
    buttonPrevHTML: null
  });
```

});

However if I add more than one to a page - the forward/back buttons control all carousels not just the one I want.  I've tried messing around with "this" to isolate the carousel element I want to change, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to get this working was to have a separately named callback function and differently named previous and next button div classes.